# Não repetição de código SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho o seguinte código no sql server. Preciso fazer com que no primeiro if ele saia e execute a mesma instrução que está dentro da tag else para não repetir o código que tem ali dentro. Como que eu faço isso?

```
DECLARE @AG_NUM varchar(15)
DECLARE @BCO_NUM VARCHAR(3)
DECLARE @AG_NUM1 varchar(15)
DECLARE @BCO_NUM1 VARCHAR(3)

SELECT TOP 1 @BCO_NUM1 = BcoNUm, @AG_NUM1 = AgNum FROM CONTA_FIN WHERE ContaFinCCorNum = '{AgNum}'

SELECT @AG_NUM = AgNum, @BCO_NUM = BcoNum FROM DUPLICATA where DupNum = '{Duplicata}'

IF (@BCO_NUM is null) OR (@AG_NUM is null)
BEGIN

    UPDATE DUPLICATA SET BcoNum = @BCO_NUM1, AgNUm = @AG_NUM1 WHERE DupNum = '{Duplicata}'

    UPDATE PARC_DOC_FIN SET BcoNum = @BCO_NUM1, AgNum = @AG_NUM1 WHERE ParcDocFinDupNum = '{Duplicata}'

END
ELSE
   -- RESTO DO CODIGO
END.
```

Comment: Eu não entendi direito a sua pergunta. Você quer que o pedaço de código no `else` sempre seja executado? Não bastaria tirar o `else` e mover as instruções para dentro do bloco principal?

Comment: se vc quer que um mesmo comando seja executado tanto no if quanto no else, seria entao o caso de tirar esse comando de dentro dos blocos de condição....

Comment: Difícil entender o que está querendo. Pois se quer executar o que estra dentro do `else` você nem precisa ter um `if`. Ou pode usar apenas o `if` para sua condição e remover o `else`.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar label e goto, mesmo não fazendo sentido neste contexto ficaria assim:

```
DECLARE @AG_NUM varchar(15)
DECLARE @BCO_NUM VARCHAR(3)
DECLARE @AG_NUM1 varchar(15)
DECLARE @BCO_NUM1 VARCHAR(3)

SELECT TOP 1 @BCO_NUM1 = BcoNUm, @AG_NUM1 = AgNum FROM CONTA_FIN WHERE ContaFinCCorNum = '{AgNum}'

SELECT @AG_NUM = AgNum, @BCO_NUM = BcoNum FROM DUPLICATA where DupNum = '{Duplicata}'

IF (@BCO_NUM is null) OR (@AG_NUM is null)
BEGIN

    UPDATE DUPLICATA SET BcoNum = @BCO_NUM1, AgNUm = @AG_NUM1 WHERE DupNum = '{Duplicata}'

    UPDATE PARC_DOC_FIN SET BcoNum = @BCO_NUM1, AgNum = @AG_NUM1 WHERE ParcDocFinDupNum = '{Duplicata}'

    goto label1 /* a execução continuará logo após o "label1" ... */
END
ELSE
   -- RESTO DO CODIGO
   label1:
   /* exatamente aqui. */
END.
```